# uninstall any ember-cli-* addon cause an error with ember-try-config

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli, eslint

Preparation:

1. install ember `npm install ember-cli`
2. start a new project: `ember new ember-demo`

Now, lets try to remove any plugin (I have tried to remove `ember-cli-jshint` and `ember-welcome-page`) and we will get broken ember project, any call to `ember` utility will cause an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ember-try-config'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/projects/ember-demo/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/ember-try/lib/utils/config.js:7:34)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

---

Here is my environment:

```
host@user $ ember --version  --verbose
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
ember-cli: 2.6.2
http_parser: 2.7.0
node: 5.11.1
v8: 4.6.85.31
uv: 1.8.0
zlib: 1.2.8
ares: 1.10.1-DEV
icu: 56.1
modules: 47
openssl: 1.0.2h
os: linux x64
```

**PREVIOUS PROBLEM**

Previously, I wanted to use **eslint** instead of **jshint** in ember app. I just followed instructions from [**ember-cli-eslint** github page](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-eslint#ember-cli--250), and run this two commands:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev ember-cli-jshint
ember install ember-cli-eslint
```

After this my project have turned into a pumpkin: no one `ember` command doesn't work, throwing an error (see above)

If you will **skip the uninstall** step - you won't get a pumpkin)) in this case `ember` continues to work as expected, but **eslint** won't be a default project's linting tool.

**DOES ANYBODY KNOW**, how to remove unused/unwanted dependencies from ember project carefully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue on github [ember-cli/ember-cli#6016](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6016). So my current workaround:

1. create new ember app
2. run `ember install ember-cli-eslint`
3. remove **ember-cli-jshint** from `package.json`
4. remove `./.jshintrc` and `./tests/.jshintrc`
5. remove local node modules `rm -rm ./node_modules`
6. reinstall node modules: `npm install`

**DONE!**

Also, there is pretty-well detailed description of installation of the eslint for ember: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-eslint#user-content-disabling-jshint

Answer (score 0):

According error message troubles caused with **ember-try** addon (https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-try ) which run tests on different environments ( check your `package.json` / `node_modules` )

If so - you can remove it or just add config file `config/ember-try.js` like ( https://github.com/vvscode/js--ember-cli-ajax-logger/blob/master/config/ember-try.js ) which define on which versions of ember you want run your tests

Comment: Hello, I have added an update to the question

**UPD 2066-06-22:**

Looks, like it is not a bug of `ember-cli-eslint` , because the same result I have gotten with `ember-welcome-page`

    npm uninstall --save-dev ember-welcome-page

Comment: @maxkoryukov did you check ember-try?